# Generator as Callback

Tags: python, callback, generator

I am looking for a way to get stuff from a callback into a generator,
or the generator to inherit the callback.

When the callback is called, the generator should run, `yield`ing the data.

```
def my_callback(some_data):
    my_generator.execute(some_data)  # what to do?

def my_generator():
    while True:
        yield some_data  # from my_callback

 # main program
 for x in my_generator:
     print(x)

# This is pseudo python code.
```

While I normally would use a queue and a thread to run and get that callback, in this case I am running inside a python extension of an cli  which calls `my_callback(data)`.
As a result, I **can't use threading**, as python will only execute that callback.
Afterwards the C part of the cli will do stuff again, and python is not executed.

**Edit**: I could register a 'poll' function, which will get called periodically. Putting a wait in there give at least the thread-queue construction some time to execute. But that feels to dirty for actual code.

Comment: Does the callback execute once or many (feeding the *generator*).  Are you looking to make a pipe of some sort?  If you use a coroutine instead of a generator you an send data to it and it can yield data or send it to another coroutine.  I'll try to whip up an example but, you should watch - http://pyvideo.org/video/213/pycon-2009--a-curious-course-on-coroutines-and-co (it is loong but worth it), the slides and files are at http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/

Comment: ... Don't recall this video but in the description: ``` inlining callback functions``` :  http://pyvideo.org/video/2575/generators-the-final-frontier

Answer (score 0):

The callback can send data to a coroutine which can send it along again if needed.
Not sure if this is what you are looking for but your question made me think of coroutines.

```
def my_callback(some_data):
    cr.send(some_data)  # what to do?

def my_coroutine(target):
    n = 0
    while True:
        data = (yield)  # from my_callback
        print 'my_callback sent: {}'.format(data)
        target.send(data)  # to my_printer

def my_printer(prefix):
    while True:
        s = (yield) # from my_coroutine
        print prefix + s

mp = my_printer('\t\t\t')
mp.next()   # advance to the first yield
cr = my_coroutine(mp)
cr.next()   # advance to the first yield

my_callback('foo')
for n in xrange(3):
    my_callback('foo' + str(n))

cr.close()
mp.close()

>>> 
my_callback sent: foo
            foo
my_callback sent: foo0
            foo0
my_callback sent: foo1
            foo1
my_callback sent: foo2
            foo2
>>>
```

If the callback execution is asynchronous, I'm not sure what would happen if the coroutine wasn't *back to* the first `yield` and the callback tries to send it something, it might throw a `ValueError: generator already executing` exception.